# How to limit the number of decimal places in yaxis in box plot

Tags: c#

1. I want to limit the number of decimal places in the y axis in the following boxplot.
2. then I want to add values to minor gridlines in the boxplot.
3. How do I limit the y axis to the minimum and maximum values in the data represented by the boxplot?
4. how do I draw a line extrapolating the averages, standard deviations of each box plot?

how do I do so in c#

[image]

Comment: You need to tell us how exactly you create the boxplot data! Do you calculate them and then add the points or do you let the chart calculate them from a data series?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SO you can only ask **one question per post**.

I will answer the first three because they are all rather simple and go together well...:

Let's start with a few short references:

```
ChartArea ca = yourChart.ChartAreas[0];

Axis ax = ca.AxisX;
Axis ay = ca.AxisY;
```

Now for the label format; this would limit the decimal places to `2`:

```
ay.LabelStyle.Format = "0.00";
```

Let's tackle the `MinorGrid` `Labels` next. **There can't be any, really.** Instead you must understand that

- `Labels, Major- and MinorGrid` all are **independent**.
- The `Labels` are spaced at `Axis.Interval`
- The `MajorGridLines` are spaced at `Axis.MajorGrid.Interval`
- The `MinorGridLines` are spaced at `Axis.MinorGrid.Interval`
- But `Axis.MajorGrid.Interval` defaults to `Axis.Interval`

This means that all you need to do it set `Axis.MinorGrid.Interval = Axis.Interval` and set `Axis.MajorGrid.Interval` **explicitly** to some larger value..:

```
ay.Interval = 10;
ay.MinorGrid.Enabled = true;
ay.MinorGrid.Interval = ay.Interval;
ay.MinorGrid.LineColor = Color.LightGray;

ay.MajorGrid.Interval = 40;
```

Use your own values!

Last point: Setting the range of the y-axis to the actual minimum and maximum values of the data..

Not really hard as well, all you need to do get at those data. How to do that depends on the details of your `Chart`.

If you only have **one** `BoxPlot` series this will do:

```
Series S = yourChart.Series[0];

double yMax = S.Points.Max(x => x.YValues.Max());
double yMin = S.Points.Min(x => x.YValues.Min());

ay.Maximum = yMax;
ay.Minimum = yMin;
```

Note that we need to get the maximum **both** over the `Points` collection **and** the YValues collection!

If you have several series, as I do, the same principle applies; we just need to add **another** loop over those series..:

```
double yMin = yourChart.Series.Select(s => s.Points.Min(x => x.YValues.Min())).Min();
double yMax = yourChart.Series.Select(s => s.Points.Max(x => x.YValues.Max())).Max();
```

[image]

Note that sometimes this cuts off the top pixel line; you can add a little slack if that happens. Maybe multiply the `yMax` by `0.001d` or another suitable number..

If you are using zoom you may want to set the AxisView min/max properties.

How hard drawing on a chart is depends on the `ChartTypes`: Anything with `Columns` or `Bars` is hard because the positions and sizes of those shapes are not accessible, afaik. This includes `BoxPlot` charts. You can try to get an answer if you post another, specific question. Do include the details (i.e. the **code**) of how you create the chart, esp. how you **add data** or how you **bind** them. Also include what exactly you want with 'extrapolating'!